# Give regular expression on language

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

What is a regular expression for $L_1=\{a^{2n} b^{3m+1} \mid n \geq 1, m \geq 0\}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: I tried. 
My answer is a(aa)*b(bbb)*

Comment: That's almost correct (the powers of $a$ are a bit off). Next time have more faith in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $L_1$ as a concatenation of two languages: $\{ a^{2n} \mid n \geq 1\}$ and $\{b^{3m+1} \mid m \geq 0\}$.